# Array Variable not being Assigned Properly in For Loop

Tags: c++, debugging, for-loop, struct

I am trying to make it so that I assign a separate address value to each of the RegType members within the struct BlockA when I create the object blockA1. They should be incremented from the address assigned to blockA1 when it is created (in this case, 3).

It works for regA (regA.addr is printed out as 4), but when I run this code, the value printed for regB.addr is some weird number, as though it had not been assigned a value at all.

This code is constructed using macros, but I tried running it on its own, as you see it here, and it says that the stack around variable A is corrupted.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

```
 struct RegTypeA {
      int addr ; int val ;
};

 struct RegTypeB {
    int addr ; int val ;
};

 struct BlockA {
    RegTypeA regA ; RegTypeB regB ;
    int addr;
    BlockA(int address);
};

BlockA::BlockA(int address) {
    addr = address;
    const int y = +1 +1;
    int A[y];
    for (int i = 0; i <= y; i++) {
        A[i] = address;
        address++;
    }
    regA.addr=A[1]; regB.addr=A[2];

}

int main()
{
    BlockA blockA1(3);

    std::cout << blockA1.regA.addr << std::endl;
    std::cout << blockA1.regB.addr;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <= y; i++)` the largest index in an array with `y` elements is `y-1` not `y`

Comment: what is the point of this array anyhow? you could simply assign values to the members directly

Comment: tobi303 Thanks. I guess I should have seen that :P. I want to be able to assign any address to the block struct and have the addresses of its members increment up from it automatically, because there are going to be a lot more regtype members when I'm done the code. I have it set up right now so that the number of regtype members is counted using macros, and the array expands accordingly. Basically, I'm setting up everything so that vals of any struct can be accessed and edited easily in int main(). It's complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its about your array `int A[y]`, which you define with a value of `y==2`, such that it actually may contain two entries, i.e. `A[0]` and `A[1]`. Note, however, that an access to `A[2]` is out of bounds, since with 0-based indices in C++  `A[2]` actually stands for a 3rd element.

While keeping the code close to yours, you could correct the issues as follows:

```
    int A[y];
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {  // Note < instead of <=
        A[i] = address;
        address++;
    }
    regA.addr=A[0]; regB.addr=A[1];  // note 0,1 instead of 1,2
```

Comment: why not simply a less obfuscated `regA.addr=adress; regB.addr=adress+1;`?

Comment: @tobi303: right, for sure. But it seems as if OP deals with "generated" code or macro-expanded code, so I left the structure as close as possible to the OP's one.

Comment: in that case I would replace "you should actually write..." with something less imperative, e.g. "The following is correct"

Comment: @tobi303: imperative was not intended. Non-native english speakers probably express things imprecise...

Comment: also non-native speaker here, and may sometimes a bit too critical. Anyhow, imho much better now